# In hive, Need a values from a table to compared with 3 different tables

Tags: database, hive

Need to compare one table with different tables:

In Hive, I need one query to compare One table with  three different lookup tables.

If the record is matched with all 3 lookup tables, record should be updated as "Passed"

If any one of the record is failed for any mis-match any of the tables, record should be updated and marked with "Failed with Reason" and Correct value should be displayed

Say:

Master Table

```
EMPNO EMPNAME Class School Marks1 Marks2 Marks3 
101   Scott   3     MOV    50     70     80 
102   Tiger   6     MVM    60     70     80
103   Rayon   7     COLORS 90     90     90
```

Lookup Tables:

EMPLOYEE:

```
EMPNO EMPNAME
101 Scott
102 Tiger
103 Spangler
104 Mike
105 Aligarh
```

Address:

```
Class School Location  PhoneNumber

4 MVM    Idaho     120232
6 TEM    Texas     120394
3 MOV    Edinburgh 120479
6 PRAM   Vatican   12098
7 LEXI   SALEM     12092
7 Colors SALEM     12092
9 Ray    Shimla    13490
```

Marks:

```
M1 M2 M3
50 60 80
50 70 80
80 74 79
90 90 90
30 50 45
```

Here, first record from Master Table will be compared with Employee Table, Address table & Markts table

1-> EmpNo 101 and EmpName Scott from Master Table matches with first record in Employee lookup table, matches with third record in Address lookup table & second record in Marks lookup table - It should be updated as passed in all tables

2-> EmpNo 102 and Empname Tiger matches with second record in Employee lookup table but does not match any record in address lookup table and does not match with Marks table
It should be updated does not match with Address and Marks table

3-> Empno 103 and Empname Rayon does not match with any record in Employee lookup table but matches with sixth record in address lookup table and matches with fourth record in Marks lookup table

Record 1 in Master Table should be updated as Passed in all 3 tables
Record 2 in Master Table should be updated as Failed in Address and Marks lookup Table
Record 3 in Master Table should be updated as Failed in Employee lookup Table

```
+-------+---------+-------+---------+--------+--------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+
| EMPNO | EMPNAME | CLASS | SCHOOL  | MARKS1 | MARKS2 | MARKS3 |                                Result                                |                       Reason                       |
+-------+---------+-------+---------+--------+--------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+
|   101 | SCOTT   |     3 | MOV     |     50 |     70 |     80 | Matched all 3 tables                                                 | NA                                                 |
|   102 | TIGER   |     6 | MVM     |     60 |     70 |     80 | Did not match in  Address and Mark Table                             | School value should be MVM  & Marks 1 should be 60 |
|   103 | RAYON   |     7 | COLORS  |     90 |     90 |     90 | Did not match in Employee look up table but other tables are matched | EMPNAME SHOULD BE RAYON                            |
+-------+---------+-------+---------+--------+--------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Add the requested result in table format and consider how exactly do you want the additional column(s) to look like

Comment: Updated the table. Thanks for looking into this!!.

Comment: O.K. but once again - consider how exactly do you want the additional column(s) to look like. Long free text does not seems to be a good idea. One option would be to use additional 3 columns, each with optional 2 values (True/False or 1/0 or Y/N)

Comment: Are the combinations in the lookup tables unique?

Comment: Yes, Combination of all the row Values in the lookup tables will be unique.Example-In Marks Table M1- 50 M2 - 60 M3- 70, Value for M1 - 50 can be repeated in the another row for M1, but combination of M1-50,60 & 70 will not be repeated again in the Marks Lookup table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives the basic representation, you can manipulate it further as you pleased.

```
select      t.*
           ,case when e.EMPNO is null then 0 else 1 end     as EMPLOYEE
           ,case when a.Class is null then 0 else 1 end     as Address
           ,case when m.M1    is null then 0 else 1 end     as Marks


from                    Master      t

            left join   EMPLOYEE    e

            on          e.EMPNO     =
                        t.EMPNO

                    and e.EMPNAME   =
                        t.EMPNAME

            left join   Address     a

            on          a.Class     =
                        t.Class

                    and a.School    =
                        t.School

            left join   Marks       m

            on          m.M1        =
                        t.Marks1

                    and m.M2        =
                        t.Marks2

                    and m.M3        =
                        t.Marks3
;
```

---

```
+--------+----------+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+
| empno  | empname  | class  | school  | marks1  | marks2  | marks3  | employee  | address  | marks  |
+--------+----------+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+
| 101    | Scott    | 3      | MOV     | 50      | 70      | 80      | 1         | 1        | 1      |
| 102    | Tiger    | 6      | MVM     | 60      | 70      | 80      | 1         | 0        | 0      |
| 103    | Rayon    | 7      | COLORS  | 90      | 90      | 90      | 0         | 0        | 1      |
+--------+----------+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks. Will give a try and let you know

Comment: Dudu, Can we get what was the mis-match value as well ?

Comment: Please open another question for that and supply a data sample and the required results in a table format.

Comment: Sure. I have opened a  new questions

Comment: Dudu, Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46270576/in-hive-need-to-print-mismatch-value-compared-from-one-master-table-in-hive-wit