# In Hive, Need to print mismatch value compared from one Master table in Hive with 3 lookup tables:

Tags: hive, hiveql

In Hive, I need one query to compare One Master table with three different lookup tables.
If the record is matched with all 3 lookup tables, record should be updated as "Passed"
If any one of the record is failed for any mis-match any of the tables, record should be updated and marked with mismatch value should be displayed

Master Table:

EMPNO EMPNAME CLASS SCHOOL LOCATION        M1 M2 M3
101          SCOTT           4           MVM      IDAHO              50   60  80
102          TIGER            7           MIV        TEXAS              50   70  80
103          RAYON         3           MOV        LONDON         80   75  80

EMPLOYEE:

```
EMPNO EMPNAME
101         SCOTT
102         TIGER
103         SPANGLER
104         MIKE
105         ALIGARGH
```

Address:

```
Class School     Location         PhoneNumber
4        MVM      IDAHO             120232
6        TEM        TEXAS             120394
3        MOV       EDINBURGH  120479
6        PRAM     VATICAN         12098
7        LEXI        SALEM            12092
7        COLORS SALEM            12092
9        RAY         SHIMLA          13490
```

Marks:

```
M1 M2 M3
50 60 80
50 60 80
80 75 80
90 90 90
30 50 45
```

Expected Result:

```
empno  | empname  | class  | school  | marks1  | marks2  | marks3  | employee  | address  | marks  | 
+--------+----------+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+
| 101    | SCOTT    | 3      | MOV     | 50      | 70      | 80      | 1         | 1        | 1      | Matched with all 3 Records
| 102    | TIGER    | 6      | MVM     | 60      | 70      | 80      | 1         | 0        | 0      |Failed with Address and Marks Table, Expected Value LEXI and TEXAS  in Address Table and  60 for M2 in Marks Table
| 103    | RAYON   | 7      | COLORS  | 90      | 90      | 90      | 0         | 0        | 1      | Failed with Employee and Address Table, Expected Value RAYON  in Employee Table and LONDON in Address Table
```

What has been done so far,

Based on this query below, I could bring the print out 0 for Mis-match and 1 for Match for each of the record in Master Table:

select      t.*
           ,case when e.EMPNO is null and e.EMPNAME is null then 0 else 1 end     as EMPLOYEE
           ,case when a.Class is null and e.school  is null then 0 else 1 end     as Address
           ,case when m.Marks1 is null and m.Marks2 is null and m.Marks3 is null then 0 else 1end     as Marks

from                    Master      t
            left join   EMPLOYEE    e
            on          e.EMPNO     =t.EMPNO
                    and e.EMPNAME   =
                        t.EMPNAME
            left join   Address     a
            on          a.Class     =
                        t.Class
                    and a.School    =
                        t.School
            left join   Marks       m
            on          m.M1        =
                        t.Marks1
                    and m.M2        =
                        t.Marks2
                    and m.M3        =
                        t.Marks3

empno  | empname  | class  | school  | marks1  | marks2  | marks3  | employee  | address  | marks  |
+--------+----------+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+
| 101    | Scott    | 3      | MOV     | 50      | 70      | 80      | 1         | 1        | 1      |
| 102    | Tiger    | 6      | MVM     | 60      | 70      | 80      | 1         | 0    | 0      |
| 103    | Rayon    | 7      | COLORS  | 90      | 90      | 90      | 0        | 0      | 1      |
+--------+----------+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+

Comment: what exactly you are looking for  it is not clear,

Comment: @Sandeep I want to view my entire master table with the matching records and mis-match value from 3 different lookup tables based on selected columns EMPNO and EMPNAME from Employee lookup table, CLASS and SCHOOL from Address Table,Marks1,Marks2 & Marks3 from Marks lookup table

Comment: @ Kaushik, I am able to view each record from Master Table to print if there is mis match or match, But I wanted to print mismatch value as well

Comment: change left join  to FULL OUTER JOIN..

Comment: Sandeep, My query already returns for every mismatch.Need help to display  the mismatch value